# Hall's theorem problem on function $f:\binom{S}{k}\to \binom {S}{k+1}$ satisfying $A\subset F(A)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $n,k$ be natural numbers with $k<\frac n2$. Let $|S|=n$. Prove there's an injection $f:\binom Sk\to \binom S{k+1}$ satisfying $A\subset f(A)$ for all $A\in \binom Sk$.

Here's what I tried.
First of all the condition $k<\frac n2$ is equivalent, I think, to the existence of an injection $f$. Second, $A\subset f(A)$ suggests modelling the problem with a bipartite graph with parts $\binom Sk,\binom S{k+1}$ such that $A,B$ are adjacent iff $A\subset B$. I think the point is to find a matching covering $\binom Sk$, since then Hall's theorem would ensure the desired condition.

To construct a matching I thought about first using $[n]$ instead of $S$, and taking $f:A\mapsto \operatorname{minsum} \left\{ B\supset A \right\} $, i.e $f$ maps $A$ into the the subset containing it having the minimal sum of elements. I think this is an injection but I'm not sure how to show this... Am I on the right track or way off?

Actually I just realized this doesn't look very injective. How about picking some total order on $\binom {[n]}{k}$ and then taking $$f:A\mapsto \operatorname{minsum} \left\{ B\supset A \text{ not yet used} \right\}?$$

Comment: You mentioned Hall's theorem but never used it, uh-huh?

Comment: @CaveJohnson if $f$ is injective, it describes a matching, so by Hall's theorem that would solve the problem.

Comment: So I think you should try to find a matching via Hall's theorem instead of constructing it yourself. Is the condition in Hall's theorem satisfied in this problem? Try to figure it out.

Comment: @CaveJohnson ugh, I mixed everything up. All clear now - Hall's theorem gives an equivalent condition for when a bipartite graph contains the graph of an injection, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I'm stuck again. We want to show that for each $U\subset \binom Sk$ we have $|U|\leq |N(U)|$, and I thought about disproving the negation. So suppose $|U|>|N(U)|$ for some $U$. This just says there are distinct $A_1,A_2\in U$ contained in the same $B\subset S$. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Recall the proof for "every $k$-regular bipartite graph has a perfect matching". Is the same method applicable in this problem?

> **Proof.** Denote the two parts of bipartite graph by $A,B$. For each subset $X\subset A$, there are $k|X|$ edges between $X$ and $N(X)$ (the neighborhood of $X$). But from each vertex in $N(X)$ there are at most $k$ edges connecting to $X$. So $|N(X)|\geq k|X|/k=|X|$. Then apply Hall's theorem.

---

**Spoiler:**

> **Proof for the original problem.** Each $k$-subset is included in $(n-k)$ many $(k+1)$-subsets. Each $(k+1)$-subset includes $k$ many $k$-subsets. In other words, for each subset $X\subset\binom{\mathcal{S}}{k}$, there are $(n-k)|X|$ edges between $X$ and $N(X)$ (the neighborhood of $X$). But from each vertex in $N(X)$ there are at most $k$ edges connecting to $X$. So $|N(X)|\geq (n-k)|X|/k>|X|$.

Comment: I don't follow.. :(

Comment: @combinarcotics I added the details.